# Why does the installation script (PetaLinux) does not find zlib1g?

Tags: ubuntu, embedded-linux, apt, dpkg, petalinux

I am trying to install PetaLinux on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.
From what I've figured out so far, the script itself seems not to be the (only) cause of the problems I am facing, so my questions has to be understood in a broader sense.

To install PetaLinux, you have to previously install some other packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtool net-tools autoconf xterm texinfo gcc-multilib gawk zlib1g libz1:i386 zlib1g-dev build-essential
```

When I now try to install PetaLinux by executing the installation script, it shows me the following error:

```
./petalinux-v2021.2-final-installer.run --dir /opt/PetaLinux
INFO: Checking installation environment requirements...
WARNING: This is not a supported OSdoes not Recognize zlib1g installation
INFO: Checking free disk space
INFO: Checking installed tools
INFO: Checking installed development libraries
ERROR: You are missing these development libraries required by PetaLinux: 

 - zlib1g:i386


Please install them with your operating system package manager, and try again
WARNING: Please install required packages.

 

Please refer to the PetaLinux Tools Installation Guide.
Check the troubleshooting guide at the end of that manual, and if you are
unable to resolve the issue please contact customer support with file:

  /home/nico/Downloads/petalinux_installation_log
```

It says it couldn't find the `zlib1g:i386` package, even though I installed `zlib1g` and `zlib1g-dev`.

The thing is, I've set up a virtual machine with the same setup, installed the same packages and the installer runs just fine and successfully finds zlib1g:i386.

My question now is, what kind failure or misconfiguration could lead to the installation script not finding said package on my machine?

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

Tried to reinstall `zlib1g` and `zlib1g-dev`

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Additionally tried to explicitly install the :i386 version (not necessary on the virtual machine anyway):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package zlib1g:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'zlib1g:i386' has no installation candidate
```

Repair the dpkg database

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Hoped you could give me some pointers about where to look at.

Comment: The provided solution `dpkg --add-architecture i386` does not work for me. The post is also 3years old and discusses the problem on Ubuntu 16 and 18. From what I've figured out, the :i386 version moved into the `zlib1g-dev` package anyway. But I could be wrong though. Long story short, I tried this already and it does not seem to work for me (see OP).

Comment: [This](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/73040?language=en_US) is mentioning ubuntu 18.....

Comment: Sure, but it also wants me to install `zlib1g:i386`. Same problem in the end (see OP). I've installed the rest of the packages in the list, but it still does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just installed `zlib1g:i386` and `zlib1g-dev:i386`. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

You can use the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zlib1g:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
```